# Getting CORS errors randomly

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, loopbackjs

I'm getting **intermittent** CORS errors on my loopback API server that's hosted on Google App Engine.

I'm trying to determine where's the error, but so far I'm unlucky.

Has anyone experienced this?

For the client side I'm using Angular 2.

Error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '(MY-SITE-URL)' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   response had HTTP status code 502.

Comment: If you are getting a 502 error, then likely none of your headers are being set by the server because it has crashed. You need to find out what is causing the 502.

Answer (score 0):

New loopback system seperates CORS from midelware.json.

did you use CORS option in that file ?

middleware.development.json

```
"initial": {
"compression": {
},
"cors": {
  "params": {
    "origin": true,
    "credentials": true,
    "maxAge": 86400
  }
}

}
```

may be this should work for you.